# Python 3.4: Checking for certain input phrase while still being able to run def's

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, phrase

In a simple text-based game I am making using Python 3.4.2, I was interested in adding an options menu.  To do this, I was hoping the user would be able to type "Options" into the chat at any time, and an options menu would pop up.  I have been reading up on similar questions, but have been unable to find anything suited for my game, where everything is taking place in various Def's, with no while statements.

Thanks in advance!

Edit : Sorry for not enough information.  Here is a snippet of my code :

```
import time
SetTimes=0

#Scrolling Up
def Entering(SetTimes):
    if SetTimes>=1:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("\n")
        SetTimes-=1
        Entering(SetTimes)
    else:
        return


#Intro Developers
def Intro(SetTimes):
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    print("blah blah blah")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("blah blah blah")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("blah blah blah")
    SetTimes=12
    Entering(SetTimes)
    SetTimes=2
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n")
    Entering(SetTimes)
    Intro2(SetTimes)
```

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is a graphical game, but the graphics are accomplished using Ascii.  The Entering(SetTimes) def  is used for making a scrolling effect for the opening scene, similar to older games.  The game will be played with the player inputting a command at specified times.  For example, it may read "There seems to be a path to the left and the right", and the user may input "Left" or "Right", but only at that specified moment.

What I am asking, is if it would be possible to have it constantly checking for you to input "Options", whilst not freezing the game.

Comment: This is too broad of a question; you need to include more context. What have you tried? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: What Cyphase said. To help you we really need to see a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have a program constantly checking for terminal input whilst not freezing the game, but the code required is a bit tricky (and OS-dependent). I strongly advise not implementing this feature until your Python skills are more advanced.

Answer (score 2):

When you want user input you need to check for user input. There's not any way around that.

### 1) Restructure your code

You probably should use some `while` statement. Usually the code looks something like:

```
init_everything()
while running:
    handle_input()
    update_everything()
    draw_everything() # or print or whatever
    if game_over():
        running = False

# display score or something
```

### 2) Use multi-threading

Don't do this. You could use two threads - one running the game and one checking for input. But don't do this. It looks like you're new to Python/game dev/programming and this will be too complicated and hard.

### 3) Use some library

Don't do everything yourself. Don't reinvent the wheel. This may be overkill for something really simple but you could really benefit from some library. [Pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html) is excelent.

### Conclusion

**1)** is simplest and probably the way to go in your case. **3)** is best in the long run. Don't use **2)**.